# cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() very slow

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I want to update/insert my table in SQL Server using C# and a stored procedure. But I found it is slow to send the data to the database using `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`, so how can I improve the speed of data transmission? Now it is about 20,000 rows/min which cannot meet performance.

```cpp
cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = @"insert_update_table";

SqlParameter p = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datatable", tempdatatable);

try
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", ex);
}
```

```sql
alter proc insert_update_table
@datatable versiontable_4 readonly
as 
begin
declare @tmptime nvarchar(255)
    begin 
        merge into dbo.CurrentVersion_1 cvr
        using @datatable src on cvr.PackageName =src.PackageName and cvr.env_cloud_roleInstance = src.env_cloud_roleInstance 
        when matched and cvr.env_time<src.env_time then 
        update set cvr.env_time=src.env_time,
        cvr.PackageVersion=src.PackageVersion,
        cvr.PackageAge=src.PackageAge,
        cvr.DownloadMechanism=src.DownloadMechanism,
        cvr.env_cloud_deploymentUnit=src.env_cloud_deploymentUnit,
        cvr.env_cloud_location=src.env_cloud_location,
        cvr.env_cloud_role=src.env_cloud_role
        when not matched by target then 
        insert(env_time,PackageName,PackageVersion,PackageAge,DownloadMechanism,
        env_cloud_roleInstance,env_cloud_deploymentUnit,env_cloud_location,env_cloud_role)
        values(src.env_time,src.PackageName,src.PackageVersion,src.PackageAge,src.DownloadMechanism,
        src.env_cloud_roleInstance,src.env_cloud_deploymentUnit,src.env_cloud_location,src.env_cloud_role);
    end 
end
```

```cpp
DataTable dt_init = new DataTable();
dt_init.Columns.Add("env_time", typeof(string));
dt_init.Columns.Add("PackageName", typeof(string));
dt_init.Columns.Add("PackageVersion", typeof(string));
dt_init.Columns.Add("PackageAge", typeof(string));
dt_init.Columns.Add("DownloadMechanism", typeof(string));
dt_init.Columns.Add("env_cloud_roleInstance", typeof(string));
dt_init.Columns.Add("env_cloud_deploymentUnit", typeof(string));
dt_init.Columns.Add("env_cloud_location", typeof(string));
dt_init.Columns.Add("env_cloud_role", typeof(string));
```

Comment: How big is the table you are trying to push to sql?

Comment: So if you comment out the contents of your SP you will be able to measure the time to transfer the data, and then when you uncomment the contents and measure the time again you'll know how much of the time is taken by the network and how much by SQL Server, and then you will know where to focus.

Comment: thank you,I comment out the contents of my sp,and the time taken is not be shortened,so I think it is some trouble about transmission.

Comment: the data I push is being generated,the generating speed is fast,so I need to improve the push speed.

Comment: If you can't get the performance you need out of your SQL, here are two ideas to consider (1) Use a simple insert (instead of a merge) into a working table, then run a server-side process to move the data from the working table to its final location, (2) Transfer the data in bulk and use `BULK INSERT`.

Comment: how can I use bulk to call a stored procedure?

Comment: Following on from @John Wu, what you need to do is to use the `SqlBulkCopy` class to bulk insert into a working table and then call a stored procedure to transfer the data from the working table to the final destination. In my experience this is the fastest way to get data into SQL Server

Comment: @kiko, if you observe simply passing the a large TVP to a proc with no implementation is slow, it may be because 1) you have not set the maximum column size for string columns in the DataTable definition (defaulting to a 2GB max and 2) you have a trace running on the server that captures the RPC and 3) you are using an older or unpatched SQL Server version.

Comment: Separately, specify a clustered primary key on the TVP type `PackageName` and `env_cloud_roleInstance` columns to improve `MERGE` performance.

Comment: ok,i will try it,thank for ur suggestion

Comment: @DanGuzman ,I have shared my datatable and I donnt konw how to set the maximum column size  for string column,do you mean typeof(string) or something else?

Comment: @kiko, set the `MaxLength` column property for string columns like: `dt_init.Columns.Add("env_time", typeof(string)).MaxLength = 20;`. It is also best to use strongly typed columns in the `DataTable` that match the TVP type columns and those should match the target table columns as well. For example, the name `env_time` suggests it should be `datetime` or `datetime2` throughout.

Answer (score 0):

`Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` command is not slow. Slow running your stored procedure. You can improve execution speed by following SQL commands. Run the commands in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and view the execution time

Comment: And more importantly: look at the actual execution plans!

Comment: but i comment out the contents of my sp,it is also slow.

Comment: I've got MS SSMS installed on the same system running an update that matches just one record via Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(). The my update statement runs in under a second in SSMS and over seven seconds via Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(). Select statements in the same program pulling much more data and writing to disk run much faster.

Comment: It may not be ExecuteNonQuery per se. My update case goes just as fast as in SSMS if I don't use AddWithValue or Add(...).Value= but instead commit the sin of embedding my values into the SQL command. Using parameters in either form goes 10x slower.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
create proc insert_update_tableNew
@datatable versiontable_4 readonly
as 
begin
declare @tmptime nvarchar(255)
    begin 
        merge into dbo.CurrentVersion_1 cvr
        using @datatable src on cvr.PackageName =src.PackageName and cvr.env_cloud_roleInstance = src.env_cloud_roleInstance 
        when matched and cvr.env_time<src.env_time then 
        update set cvr.env_time=src.env_time,
        cvr.PackageVersion=src.PackageVersion,
        cvr.PackageAge=src.PackageAge,
        cvr.DownloadMechanism=src.DownloadMechanism,
        cvr.env_cloud_deploymentUnit=src.env_cloud_deploymentUnit,
        cvr.env_cloud_location=src.env_cloud_location,
        cvr.env_cloud_role=src.env_cloud_role
        when not matched by target then 
        insert(env_time,PackageName,PackageVersion,PackageAge,DownloadMechanism,
        env_cloud_roleInstance,env_cloud_deploymentUnit,env_cloud_location,env_cloud_role)
        values(src.env_time,src.PackageName,src.PackageVersion,src.PackageAge,src.DownloadMechanism,
        src.env_cloud_roleInstance,src.env_cloud_deploymentUnit,src.env_cloud_location,src.env_cloud_role);
    end 
end
```

create Your Procedure with new name and recall again.

this solution worked for me!

Last Run time about 6 minutes

New Run time about 4 seconds

Comment: Your answer seems more like a question. If that is the case, please ask it in a separate post.